# Single-instance background process with reloading

Tags: shell

Is there a shell tool that takes an arbitrary executable and makes a detectable, restartable background process out of it?

If I had to script this myself, I would use a `$PIDFILE` and something along the lines of...

```
if [ -f $PIDFILE ] && ps -p `cat $PIDFILE` &> /dev/null; then
    # Already running, kill, restart
else
    # Stale pidfile, start
fi
```

This sounds like there's a program that does this a thousand times better than anything I'd come up with, though. Is there?

If there isn't, what caveats and gotchas should I be aware of in implementing a script as the above?

Answer (score 0):

On Debian systems there is `start-stop-daemon`.  I recommend using that, and if you're not on Debian or Ubuntu, just copy that script from Debian and try it.

Comment: Can you give me an example user-space, shell session usage? I thought `start-stop-daemon` was meant for system services?

Comment: I'll refer you to the man pages, since I don't have a system with `start-stop-daemon` in front of me.  You'll need to pass a few arguments like `--start --name foo --pidfile /tmp/foo.pid`.  There's no explicit "restart" feature, so for that you'll need to just do `--stop --oknodo` followed by `--start`.

Comment: That's okay, knowing that the tool is suited for the job is enough. I'll do a bit of reading and get back here

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it in a shell script, you can use subshells and do something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
(
while true; do
  echo "I'm process A"
  sleep 1
done
) &
(
while true; do
  echo "I'm process B"
  sleep 3
done
) &
wait
wait
```

The commands in parentheses are run in the background, because if the ampersand, and the wait commands, makes sure the parent scripts does not exit. It's possible save the pid of the subshells by saving `$!` after each subshell.

Comment: The second call to `wait` is unnecessary. The first one will not return until *all* background processes complete.

Answer (score 0):

Historically, such process monitoring was done by the `init` program. Today, `init` may have been replaced by your operating system by one of several proposed replacements: `upstart`, `systemd`, `launchd` (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Init for a longer list). Check which your OS uses to see how it creates and monitors long-running processes.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'm familiar with `systemd` and `upstart`, but I want to do this in user-space, within a regular shell session, no elevated priviledges. This is not a system service.